# install packages and get autocompletion on Monaco editor react

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco, unpkg

I want to give my users the ability to install npm packages in the browser and get autocompletion on the Monaco editor for the installed packages, I have searched a lot, and this is what I came up with for now:

```
const { data: cryptoTypeDefs } = await axios.get(
        `https://unpkg.com/@types/node/crypto.d.ts`
      );
```

```
  monaco?.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
        cryptoTypeDefs,
        "crypto.d.ts"
      );
```

but this way is very tedious and I want a dynamic way to do this for installed packages,
here as you see I just extracted the crypto module alone from @types/node package.

Comment: Why's that tedious? You are adding two lines per library! I consider that super easy.

Comment: I need the way to be more dynamic, like I need to install every package in a standard way, here I am pulling the crypto module alone from package @types/node, I have no clue how to pull every module type defs from the package

Comment: Then this is probably not a Monaco editor problem as such, but has to do with getting the individual typings. You may want to ask this as an own question.